# SQL Table Valued Function is not working

Tags: sql-function

I have an sql query that retrieves about 2500 rows in 1 second. When i put this query in a table valued function it took 20 minutes and only retrieved 450-500 rows and it was still running.

```
select g.AccountNumber,g.AccountName,g.ProductNumber,g.ProductName,g.SlsNumber,g.SlsName,g.GoalAmount,s.SalesAmount
from
    (
        select g.AccountNumber,g.AccountName,g.ProductNumber,g.ProductName,g.SlsNumber,g.SlsName,sum(g.GoalAmount) GoalAmount
        from RucoNetApiBase.dbo.Goals g with(nolock)
        where ((@month <> 0 and g.Month_=@month) or (@month=0 and 1=1)) and (g.Year_=year(getdate()))
        group by g.AccountNumber,g.AccountName,g.ProductNumber,g.ProductName,g.SlsNumber,g.SlsName
    ) g left outer join
    (
        select s.ClientCode,left(s.ItemCode,5) ItemCode,s.SalesmanCode,sum(s.Amount) SalesAmount
        from dbo.V_NetSalesBase s
        where ((@month <> 0 and s.Month_=@month) or (@month=0 and 1=1)) and (s.Year_=year(getdate())) and (s.FicheSpeCode='')
        group by s.ClientCode,left(s.ItemCode,5),s.SalesmanCode
    ) s on (g.AccountNumber=s.ClientCode) and (g.ProductNumber=s.ItemCode) and (g.SlsNumber=s.SalesmanCode)
```

And the function;

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[F_GoalSummary]
(
   @month int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
select g.AccountNumber,g.AccountName,g.ProductNumber,g.ProductName,g.SlsNumber,g.SlsName,g.GoalAmount,s.SalesAmount
from
    (
        select g.AccountNumber,g.AccountName,g.ProductNumber,g.ProductName,g.SlsNumber,g.SlsName,sum(g.GoalAmount) GoalAmount
        from RucoNetApiBase.dbo.Goals g with(nolock)
        where ((@month <> 0 and g.Month_=@month) or (@month=0 and 1=1)) and (g.Year_=year(getdate()))
        group by g.AccountNumber,g.AccountName,g.ProductNumber,g.ProductName,g.SlsNumber,g.SlsName
    ) g left outer join
    (
        select s.ClientCode,left(s.ItemCode,5) ItemCode,s.SalesmanCode,sum(s.Amount) SalesAmount
        from dbo.V_NetSalesBase s
        where ((@month <> 0 and s.Month_=@month) or (@month=0 and 1=1)) and (s.Year_=year(getdate())) and (s.FicheSpeCode='')
        group by s.ClientCode,left(s.ItemCode,5),s.SalesmanCode
    ) s on (g.AccountNumber=s.ClientCode) and (g.ProductNumber=s.ItemCode) and (g.SlsNumber=s.SalesmanCode)
)
```

and use of function;

```
SELECT [t0].[AccountNumber], [t0].[AccountName], [t0].[ProductNumber], [t0].[ProductName], [t0].[SlsNumber], [t0].[SlsName], [t0].[GoalAmount], [t0].[SalesAmount]
FROM [dbo].[F_GoalSummary](5) AS [t0]
ORDER BY [t0].[ProductName]
```

if a execute query itself in management studio every thing is fine(2500 rows in 1 second) but when i put the query text in a table valued function and use it in a query i get only 450 rows in 20 minutes. It was still running. That function was running fine yesterday.

i am using sql server 2008 r2
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      10.50.1600.1
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        10.50.1600.1
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7600.16385
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     8.0.7600.16385
Microsoft .NET Framework                        2.0.50727.4963
Operating System                        6.1.7600

A simple work around can be, not to using functions. but a have more complicated functions that i used clr stored procedures in and can't easily copy paste.

i have no idea what is difference between those two.

please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the results of the two queries you try to join into a table variable and join those two variables?

What happens if you don't order the results?